# Which signal should be fed into the single ended input of the PAM8320?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, schematics, dac

I'm feeding audio from this [DY-SV17F](https://www.thebackshed.org/forum/uploads/Grogster/2022-11-17_193909_DY-SV17F%20module%20functions%20introduction.pdf) module into this [PAM8320](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8320.pdf) amplifier.

The configurations I believe I can choose from are:

1: Feed either DACL or DACR from the module to the amplifier.

2: Combine DACL and DACR from the module to the amplifier via 1kΩ resistors.

3: Feed SPK+ from the module to the amplifier, leave SPK- floating.

4: Feed SPK+ from the module to the amplifier, connect SPK- to system ground.

5: Combine SPK+ and SPK- from the module to the amplifier via 1kΩ resistors.

6: None of the above (but please share how you would interface).

Answer (score 0):

1. Should work.
2. Should work. That's approximately what the DY module does onboard already for the mono speaker output.
3. Do not connect class D speaker level output to amplifier input.
4. That's two forbidden things that can do damage, due to output being class D and shorting other class D output to ground.
5. You get silence out in the form of common mode DC bias voltage and the differential AC audio signals cancel each other out.
6. Depends what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: For reference my vote was 1 or 2, but other designers I work with suggested 3-5 which I share the same concerns you mentioned. For #6 all I really want to achieve is a configuration that will work reliably. I don't mind setting this PCB up with different configs through jumpers and removing 0402s for debug but if there is 100% confidence in 1 or 2 I would likely just go with 2 and not include any debug options for this PCB.

Comment: @BenjaminMcCabe You might still need debug options. Do you know if the output and input amplitudes match, do you need to AC couple the output or input, do you need to attenuate resistively or have settable gain with op-amps. So how to make connections in general does not tell how they should be made in detail. And it is weird to add a separate Class D amplifier for single speaker since the module already has a similar built-in Class D speaker amp.

Comment: From what I've observed the 5W onboard amp is severely overrated even driving a 4Ω load. We need something more powerful for the environment this will operate in. I'm not sure about the output/input amplitudes, but yes there is a 4.7kΩ resistor and cap in series with the PAM8320 input.